# Setting API data as state in React is undefined, but the API data exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, state

I have a weird issue with my React state. I'm fetching data from my NodeJS backend, and it comes back correctly in my frontend React app. But when I try to initialize a state with the data that was fetched, the state's value is "undefined", even though I know the data is coming back from the backend correctly.

here are the important parts of my react code:

```
const [currentCityData, setCurrentCityData] = useState({});

const fetchData = (cityValue) => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/get-weather', {
            params: {
                cityValue: cityValue
            }
        })
            .then(res => console.log(res?.data?.data[0]))
            .then((res) => setCurrentCityData(res?.data?.data[0]))
            .then(console.log(currentCityData))
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    };

useEffect(() => {
        fetchData('toronto&country=canada');
    }, []);
```

I'm getting the weather of a city. When I do a console log of the data I get back `.then(res => console.log(res?.data?.data[0]))` inside `fetchData`, the data is correct (its just an object with many weather properties). The line after that I set my state `currentCityData`, but then when I console log my `currentCityData` right after, its `undefined`.

Exactly what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning aything from the first promise `then` handler. :

```
  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/get-weather', {
        params: {
            cityValue: cityValue
        }
    })
        .then(res => console.log(res?.data?.data[0])) // <--- here you should return 
        .then((res) => setCurrentCityData(res?.data?.data[0]))
        .then(console.log(currentCityData))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
};
```

change your code to :

```
  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/get-weather', {
        params: {
            cityValue: cityValue
        }
    })
        .then(res => {console.log(res?.data?.data[0]); return res?.data?.data[0] }) // <--- here you should return 
        .then((res) => setCurrentCityData(res?.data?.data[0]))
        .then(console.log(currentCityData))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
};
```

Demo : [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-esjujq?file=src/App.js)